# WCF 4 REST Max recevied message size

Tags: wcf, rest

I am testing a WCF 4 Rest interface.

When trying to do a get using fiddler I receive this:
"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."

I have tried to increase it in my web.config file but it does not come through:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="327680" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Thanks,
Mikkel

Comment: Are you sure your message must be so long? Your problem could be there (and be even bigger than the new maximum value).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this today, and it was a bit of a pain to figure out. The following config (adapted from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056730/configuring-wcf-4-with-routing-global-asax-for-both-http-https-endpoints)) should work:

```
<system.web>
  <!-- maxRequestLength is in KB -->
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="320" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="327680" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name=""
                        helpEnabled="true"
                        automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm pretty sure you need the `httpRuntime` bit because you're running with aspNetCompatibilityEnabled set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Try it by following web-config(in Service) settings :

```
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>

            <webHttpEndpoint>
                <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"                                        
                                  crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" 
                                  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                                  maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                                  maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" />
            </webHttpEndpoint>

    </standardEndpoints>

    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding>
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture WCF traces at verbose level with ActivityTracing and check what enpoints are applied on your service under Construct ServiceHost and Open ServiceHost activity. That will give you idea whether above configuration is applied on service or not.

HTH,
Amit

Comment: It will be required to get large amounts of data in som scenarios. I have changed the config to '<webHttpEndpoint> <!-- Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below --> <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" maxBufferSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="400000000"/> </webHttpEndpoint>'. I am testing from Fiddler2 and I do not know how set client config using fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you increased the **MaxReceivedMessageSize** value in both the web.config (service-side) and in your client's configuration (file)?

If so, can you also try to increase **MaxBufferSize** to the same value as **MaxReceivedMessageSize**?